# Converting domain names to idn in python

Tags: python, unicode

I have a long list of domain names which I need to generate some reports on. The list contains some IDN domains, and although I know how to convert them in python on the command line:

```
>>> domain = u"pfarmerü.com"
>>> domain
u'pfarmer\xfc.com'
>>> domain.encode("idna")
'xn--pfarmer-t2a.com'
>>>
```

I'm struggling to get it to work with a small script reading data from the text file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

infile = open(sys.argv[1])

for line in infile:
    print line,
    domain = unicode(line.strip())
    print type(domain)
    print "IDN:", domain.encode("idna")
    print
```

I get the following output:

```
$ ./idn.py ./test 
pfarmer.com
<type 'unicode'>
IDN: pfarmer.com

pfarmerü.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./idn.py", line 9, in <module>
    domain = unicode(line.strip())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have also tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import codecs

infile = codecs.open(sys.argv[1], "r", "utf8")

for line in infile:
    print line,
    domain = line.strip()
    print type(domain)
    print "IDN:", domain.encode("idna")
    print
```

Which gave me:

```
$ ./idn.py ./test       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./idn.py", line 8, in <module>
    for line in infile:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/codecs.py", line 679, in next
    return self.reader.next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/codecs.py", line 610, in next
    line = self.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/codecs.py", line 525, in readline
    data = self.read(readsize, firstline=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/codecs.py", line 472, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-5: unsupported Unicode code range
```

Here is my test data file:

```
pfarmer.com
pfarmerü.com
```

I'm very aware of my need to understand unicode now.

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you need to know in which encoding you file was saved. This would be something like 'utf-8' (which is NOT Unicode) or 'iso-8859-1' or 'cp1252' or alike.

Then you can do (assuming 'utf-8'):

```
infile = open(sys.argv[1])

for line in infile:
    print line,
    domain = line.strip().decode('utf-8')
    print type(domain)
    print "IDN:", domain.encode("idna")
    print
```

Convert encoded strings to unicode with `decode`. Convert unicode to string with `encode`. If you try to encode something which is already encoded, python tries to decode first, with the default codec 'ascii' which fails for non-ASCII-values.

Comment: Reference: codecs — Codec registry and base classes — Python 3 documentation - https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#module-encodings.idna

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is fine, except that:

```
domain = unicode(line.strip())
```

you have to specify a particular encoding here: `unicode(line.strip(), 'utf-8')`. Otherwise you get the default encoding which for safety is 7-bit ASCII, hence the error. Alternatively you can spell it `line.strip().decode('utf-8')` as in knitti's example; there is no difference in behaviour between the two syntaxes.

However judging by the error “can't decode byte 0xfc”, I think you haven't actually saved your `test` file as UTF-8. Presumably this is why the second example, that also looks OK in principle, fails.

Instead it's ISO-8859-1 or the very similar Windows code page 1252. If it's come from a text editor on a Western Windows box it will certainly be the latter; Linux machines use UTF-8 by default instead nowadays. Either make sure to save your file as UTF-8, or read the file using the encoding `'cp1252'` instead.