# Python function to turn internationalized domain name from U-Label to A-Label?

Tags: python, unicode, internationalization

Is there a Python function to convert a U-label domain name to an A-label one?

I coded this, but I'm not sure that it's correct:

```
def ulabel_to_alabel(ulabel):
   for ch in ["\u3002","\uff0e","\uff61"]:
       ulabel = ulabel.replace(ch,".")
   labels = [encodings.idna.ToASCII(label) for label in ulabel.split(".")]
   return ".".join(labels)
```

The problem with just calling `encodings.idna.ToASCII(label)` is that it doesn't handle periods properly, and it doesn't preserve label parts that don't require conversion.

For example:

```
>>> print(ulabel_to_alabel(u"matías.eu"))
xn--matas-1sa.eu
>>> print(encodings.idna.ToASCII(u"matías.eu"))
xn--matas.eu-e2a
```

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760338/converting-domain-names-to-idn-in-python answer your question?